# I want to create an Anova Table with Dataset having one dependent column and otheras independent column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anova

I have a data set having columns col1, col2,col3,col4,col5. I want col1 as dependent variable and other as independent variable. How would i create the formula?
I am creating like this.
I confused what should be the **?**

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
model = ols('anovaData["col1"] ~ anovaData["?"]', data=anovaData).fit()
```

Edit1 :
I put required columns in a list and fed ols as independent variable. that works fine but the format that i want is not as required.

```
y = [col2,col3,col4,col5]
model = ols('anovaData["col1"] ~ anovaData[y]', data=anovaData).fit()
```

```
====================================================================================
                       coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept           -0.0177      0.013     -1.319      0.190      -0.044       0.009
anovaData[y][0]      0.0003      0.001      0.211      0.833      -0.002       0.003
anovaData[y][1]     -0.0007      0.000     -3.829      0.000      -0.001      -0.000
anovaData[y][2]      0.0032      0.001      2.853      0.005       0.001       0.005
anovaData[y][3]     -0.0008      0.000     -2.162      0.032      -0.002   -7.22e-05
```

what is want is

```
====================================================================================
                       coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept           -0.0177      0.013     -1.319      0.190      -0.044       0.009
col2                 0.0003      0.001      0.211      0.833      -0.002       0.003
col3                -0.0007      0.000     -3.829      0.000      -0.001      -0.000
col4                 0.0032      0.001      2.853      0.005       0.001       0.005
col5                -0.0008      0.000     -2.162      0.032      -0.002   -7.22e-05
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Works for me

```
formula = 'col1 ~ ' + ' + '.join(['%s' % variable for variable in y])
model = ols(formula=formula, data=anovaData).fit()
```